# What is the channel uri when registering a device via Microsoft's Azure Create a Registration call

Tags: c#, azure, api, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Following what's outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-registration) I've been able to so far read all registered devices, delete a device registration by id, and get a specific device registration by tag. What I want to do is register a device with a specific tag.

I found the page that specifies using this POST endpoint:

```
https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/registrations/?api-version=2015-01
```

I've applied the correct headers - Content Type, Authorization, and x-ms-version.

My question comes in the XML body that is getting sent. Where do I find the correct **ChannelUri** or is there something else in Azure / Firebase that I should be using in place of the channel uri?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<content type="application/xml">
    <WindowsRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
        <Tags>myTag, myOtherTag</Tags>
        <ChannelUri>{ChannelUri}</ChannelUri>
    </WindowsRegistrationDescription>
</content>
```

Also, am I correct in thinking that the above api call will successfully register a device with the azure notification hub or am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The ChannelUri is a value that will be provided to you via UWP that allows you to target the particular Windows machine your application is running on (e.g.the example that you've provided above is WNS specific payload.)

Each Push Notification Service (PNS) has its own mechanism for uniquely identifying a device that should receive notifications. Other examples are included on the reference page you found, for instance you'll notice that Apple devices require a `DeviceToken` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I didn't even notice that I was using the payload for WNS. I should have been using the one for Android which looks like it wants the GCM Registration ID. Is this something that I can get from inside Azure? Is this the same thing as the API key that I have tied to the GCM device under settings? Sorry for all the questions. I'm just trying to pick up as much as I can about push notifications :)

Comment: Actually @MarStr, if you don't mind me asking another question, is the process the same when trying to register a device through their APIs as it is using code behind? I found a tutorial before that has code that looks like its creating a token and then registering the token with the server. I believe this also assigns the token to the device (could be wrong) but the tutorial didn't really explain that part a lot. do you know if theres a part of the APIs that actually takes the newly created registration ID and assigns it to the device? Again, sorry for the bombardment of questions.